# Normal flair not linked but combined flair is

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair, combined-flair

When I go to my profile and look at my flairs I noticed something strange. I saw that the normal flairs (the ones including only the rep of the current site) are not linked. However when I looked at the combined flair I saw that this is the only one with the link. As seen in the HTML snippet the normal ones should link to.

So my question is: is this a bug, forgot to link or by design?

Comment: I would guess it's by design, no point linking back to your own profile in the preview (only you can see the "flair" tab) but as I can't be sure, it's a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hyperlinking feature was there, but was opted out since like forever. I enabled it for the sake of consistency. It'll be rolled out with the 2013.7.10.830 release.